# Issue on drush 9 alias file location

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drush

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587919/where-drush-9-aliases-file-should-be-located-in-drupal-8) and with local installation of Drush 9 as adviced by the official website (not globally installed), I put my Drush8 alias file into: `~/.drush/sites`, in addition of the `~/www/domain/sited8/drush/sites` default folder. And I edited the `~/.drush/drush.yml` file to add my other path to alias files.

Then I run  `~ $ drush site:alias-convert` and get:
 `Absolute path to a directory for writing new alias files [~/www/domain/sited8/drush/sites]: !`!
Then drupal ccreate converted files into this folder. It seem to ignore my other folder..

Actually I get only one website but I will add others, so I want to have my alias files into a root folder instead of a drupal website folder (it will not be a multisite install).

So why drush doesn't look an dwork into my `~/.drush/sites` folder ?

EDIT: after convertion, I move files to `~/.drush/sites` then with drush sa I get a list like :

```
'@sited8ce.prod':
  root: ~/www/celony/sited8
  uri: 'https://www.lycee-celony.com/'
'@sited8mg.dev':
  root: ~/www/mgasquet/sited8
  uri: 'http://d8-lycee-marie-gasquet.eu'
```

but when I try to use one of them I get partial status info:

```
$ drush @sited8ce.prod status
 PHP binary    : /php/7.2.14/bin/php
 PHP config    : ~/admin/config/php/php.ini
 PHP OS        : Linux
 Drush script  : ~/www/mgasquet/sited8/vendor/drush/drush/drush
 Drush version : 9.7.1
 Drush temp    : /tmp
 Drush configs : ~/.drush/drush.yml
                 ~/www/mgasquet/sited8/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
```

Drush is locally installed in both websites but the drush folder is only present on one..I don't understand the logic here..
Because alias doesn't work:

```
 ~ $ drush @sited8ce.prod pml | grep goo
     Command pml was not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to run Drupal-specific commands.
```

Comment: This is  `~/.drush/sites` and `~/.drush/drush.yml`, the tilde `~` is missing in your path, it expands to the value of current user's `$HOME` directory.

Comment: Yes I ommit the ~ but when I do drush sa I get the alias list like you can see in my  initial edited post.